# Programs installed with depothelper dump core

Tags: hp-ux

Anything I install via [depothelper](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/depothelper-2.00/) on HP-UX 11.23 (ia64) seems to crash. I installed the packages using the following command:

`/depothelper -a ia64 -c /var/tmp/mydir -o 11.23 vim`

And here is what I get when I try to execute the programs:

```
bash-2.05b# whereis vim
whereisvim: /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/local/man/man1/vim.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/vim.1
bash-2.05b# whereis rsync
rsync: /usr/local/bin/rsync /usr/local/share/man/man1/rsync.1
bash-2.05b# /usr/local/bin/rsync
Bus error (core dumped)
bash-2.05b# /usr/local/bin/vim
Bus error (core dumped)
```

The system is an RX1620 and everything else seems to work just fine on it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the new version of the `depothelper` package using `depothelper` itself, and removed and re-installed the programs and they now work.